# "Node" is ambiguous only in one source file C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm converting a Java program of mine that solves an image of a maze into C++, however vscode is telling me that `"Node" is ambiguous` for every mention of `Node` in `converter.cpp` and `converter.h`

`converter.cpp`

```
#include "headers/Converter.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;

Converter::Converter(std::string path){
    img = imread(path, IMREAD_COLOR);
    this->path = path;

    if(!img.data){ // check if file can be read
        throw std::logic_error("Image could not be read; check file path");
    }

    // get dimensions
    width = img.cols;
    height = img.rows;
}

// actually returns a vector but close enough
std::vector<std::vector<Node>> Converter::to2Darray(){
    std::vector<std::vector<Node>> nodes(width);

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        std::vector<Node> row(height);
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            row[j](j, i, false);
        }
        nodes.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

`converter.h`

```
#include <string>
#include "Node.h"
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp>

class Converter{
    private:
        std::string path;
        cv::Mat img;
        int height, width;
    
    public:
        Converter(std::string path);
        std::vector<std::vector<Node>> to2Darray();
        void toImage(std::vector<std::vector<Node>> graph, std::vector<Node> solution);
        Node getEndNode();
        Node getStartNode();
};
```

Compiling from the terminal with ` g++ *.cpp "pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4" -g gives a different error that seems to be related

```
Converter.cpp:23:25: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   23 | std::vector<std::vector<Node>> Converter::to2Darray(){
      |                         ^~~~
Converter.cpp:23:25: error: template argument 2 is invalid
Converter.cpp:23:29: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   23 | std::vector<std::vector<Node>> Converter::to2Darray(){
      |                             ^~
Converter.cpp:23:29: error: template argument 2 is invalid
Converter.cpp:23:32: error: no declaration matches ‘int Converter::to2Darray()’
   23 | std::vector<std::vector<Node>> Converter::to2Darray(){
```

Comment: Where is the node.h file

Comment: Only guessing at the answer without seeing `Node.h`

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV has [`Node`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d3/de3/classcv_1_1Node.html) class, so `using namespace cv;` prevents the compiler from telling whether `Node` is your `Node` (possibly in `Node.h`) or `Node` from `OpenCV`.

If `Node` in your source mean ones from `Node.h`, you should stop using `using namespace cv;` and use `cv::imread` instead of `imread`.